# What does "their" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns, possessives, subjects, anaphora

I'm having a hard time with this sentence:

> Professional bodies will monitor, and if necessary, discipline members who do not adhere to their ethical principles.

Does 'their' refer to the members or to the professional bodies?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I would say that the sentence is ambiguous in regard to whose ethical principles are in focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Nigel J in that the sentence is ambiguous, but if I had to guess:

### Short answer

'Their' refers to the professional bodies.

### Explanation

From a practical standpoint, a professional body probably doesn't exist to enforce one member's set of ethical principles, which may differ from one member to another. Rather, a professional body likely exists to enforce the agreed-upon ethical principles of an organization with which that professional body is associated.

Comment: I agree. Grammatically, it could be either. (Although on a purely grammatical basis, pronouns most often refer to the subject or object closest to them.) But logically, it's referencing *professional bodies*. If the sentence was actually referring to the members' ethical principles, I would have expected it to read something like *who do not* ***each*** *adhere to their* ***own*** *ethical principles.*

Comment: This is what I thought too - why bring them up at all if it's not a single standard? And how could one professional body police their members' individual ethics? Thank you for clarifying